# CodeIgniter 4 - extend/replace/override CodeIgniter\Images\Handlers\BaseHandler::getEXIF()

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-processing

Trying CI4 after a long time away from CI3. Been at this for a while and cannot seem to get it right...

`exif_read_data` is throwing errors instead of returning `false` so I want to prefix it with `@` as follows.

All I want to do is replace `CodeIgniter\Images\Handlers\BaseHandler::getEXIF()` with:

```
public function getEXIF(string $key = null, bool $silent = false) {
    if (! function_exists('exif_read_data') && $silent) {
        return null;
    }
    $exif = null; // default
    switch ($this->image()->imageType) {
        case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
        case IMAGETYPE_TIFF_II:
            $exif = @exif_read_data($this->image()->getPathname());
            if (! is_null($key) && is_array($exif)) {
                $exif = $exif[$key] ?? false;
            }
    }
    return $exif;
}
```

Edited `system/Images/Handlers/BaseHandler.php` directly as a quick-fix but want to extend the core properly.

Simply cannot figure out the proper namespace, paths and config to make this override load.

Comment: My current namespace and class definition...

`<?php namespace App\Libraries;

class BaseHandler extends CodeIgniter\Images\Handlers\BaseHandler {`

I have tried creating the override in `App\Libraries\Images\Handlers` as well. Still doesn't load :(